# Greping strings from different lines of nmap output

Tags: awk, sed, grep, output, nmap

I have the following nmap output:

```
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.14
Host is up (0.13s latency).
PORT    STATE  SERVICE VERSION
110/tcp closed pop3    
--
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.15
Host is up (0.13s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE    VERSION
110/tcp open  pop3       Popper
--
Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.20
Host is up (0.13s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE VERSION
110/tcp open  pop3    Dove
```

which I get using the command: `nmap -p 110 -sV 192.168.1.10-20`

**Note:** I have not used the -oG output format with nmap because I understand that it is deprecated.

The output I require:

```
192.168.1.15 open Popper
192.168.1.20 open Dove
```

As you can see it should print the IP address, the State and Version of only the OPEN ports

What I have tried:

Using all sorts of variations (of the command below) using grep and awk to get my required output but cannot get it too work how I want it to:

```
nmap -p 110 -sV 192.168.1.10-20 | grep -B3 'open' | egrep -o "([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}"
```

The difficulty I am having is how to extract specific parts from different lines of the output and put them together

### Update

I have found that sometimes in the VERSION column there are more than just single words e.g sometimes it may say `Popper 1.2.7-Beta` rather than just `Popper`. In which case it then just prints `1.2.7-Beta` instead of `Popper 1.2.7-Beta` (because the space between the words confuses it). How would you deal with this occurring?

Comment: You would be just fine using the `-oG` format for this purpose. What Nmap means by "deprecated" is that the format is frozen and new features will not be added to it. Therefore it represents only a small part of Nmap's possible output. It is not going anywhere, though, and does contain the parts that you need in an easy-to-parse format.

Comment: @bonsaiviking - Ah excellent, I assumed it meant it would be removed at some point. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '/Nmap scan report/ { host=$NF } NF==4 && $2=="open" { print host, $2, $NF }' nmap-output.txt
```

Explanation:

1) For any line that matches the string "Nmap scan report", remember the last field of the line in the variable name "host"

2) For any line that has 4 fields and where the second field matches the string "open", print the remembered "host" variable, the second field of this line ("open"), and the last field of the line (what is in the Version column).

Comment: Could you explain what each part does please? thanks

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I have found that sometimes in the VERSION column there are more than just single words e.g sometimes it may say `Popper 1.2.7-Beta` rather than just `Popper`. In which case it then just prints `1.2.7-Beta` instead of `Popper 1.2.7-Beta`. How would you deal with this occurring? thanks

Comment: I suppose one way to do that would be to erase the two fields you don't want, and print the resulting line - replace the `print` portion  with `$1=""; $3=""; print host, $0`. Another way would be to loop over `$4` .. `$NF` and print them each... There would be another option if the fields are separated by tabs, but I don't know if that's the case with `nmap`...

Answer (score 0):

How about this awk:

```
awk '/^Nmap/{a=$5}
     /^110\/tcp open/{print a,$2,$3}' Your_file
```